# end of line issues reading txt file in R

Tags: r, txt

I am having some issues reading a txt file in R that I presume is created by end of line issues. I have a dataframe that contains two columns: the first column contains a label in the form __label__1234 and the second column is a string of text (I can't share what the actual text is for privacy reasons, but it would be something like, I WORK AT MACDONALDS). I first use write.table to store this information in a text file as so

```
write.table(test,"test.txt",sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE
```

I then attempt later to read that text file back into R and I get undesireable results.

```
data<-read.table("test.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

The data comes out looking similar to

```
           V1                V2
1 __label__001 I WORK AT WENDYS
2 __label__002 I WORK AT BK
3 __label__001 I WORK AT WENDYS\n__label__002\tI WORK AT BK\n__label__003\tI WORK AT FIVE GUYS
```

When what I desire is

```
           V1                V2
1 __label__001 I WORK AT WENDYS
2 __label__002 I WORK AT BK
3 __label__001 I WORK AT WENDYS
4 __label__002 I WORK AT BK
5 __label__003 I WORK AT FIVE GUYS
```

Any idea what I can change either in the read or the write to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand why, so maybe someone with more knowledge can put it as an answer but adding quote="" to my read.table command gave me the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Must have data reasons. I simulated your example dataset

```r
V1 = paste0("__label__00",c(1,2,1,2,3))
V2 = paste("I WORK AT",c("WENDYS","BK","WENDYS","BK","FIVE GUYS"))
test = data.frame(V1,V2)
```

and executed your write/read commands

```r
write.table(test,"test.txt",sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
data = read.table("test.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

which gave me your desired output. I was not able to reproduce your undesired output. So I suggest that you look for differences in your data compared to mine.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go. Definitely has to do with the data. The actual data is a lot messier, different characters, spacing etc. but it all looks fine, in that I can't see anything in the data that would cause it. And again, due to the sensitivity of the data I can't share the actual data.